# Visual Studio Git Changes sees only current project VS2022

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control, visual-studio-2022

I have solution with few projects added to git repo separately / located in other folder trees.
But VS sees only one (main) project as GIT controlled - as shown below -> single lock icon in solution tree

In VS2017 I was using **[EZ-Git extension](https://github.com/jzoss/Git-Source-Control-Provider)** - with this one I was able to commit changes to any project added to solution.
Unfortunately this extension is not working with VS2022

So I wonder if there is any way to force VS changes to see all projects in solution ?

PS I know I can use external tools / console to commit changes, but I want to have that in IDE

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-repo support can be enabled under `Tools`->`Options...`->`Preview Features` and ticking the `Enable multi-repo support` option:

[image]